# The Text in Android Studio Design Editor Preview is Pixelated

Tags: android-studio

I have updated my android studio to version 3.1.3. After the update the text and other items inside design editor looks blurry and pixelated when the preview is scaled to a zoom other than 100%. In the previous versions the text was much smoother. Is this a issue of my computer display settings or any other error? Can someone tell me if there is any method to fix this issue?

Comment: [Blurry Pixelated Text - Zoom: 28%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfDeb.jpg)

 [Clear Text - Zoom: 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXhTX.jpg)